# Any alternative to Storybook, that can be used with react-native ( using expo )?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, storybook

I want to create a component library, so i can keep track of what i have, easier. Something similar to what Storybook is doing.

I'm using react-native with expo. I have tried runing storybook and it did not worked, after long tries to make it work, found out that storybook is not compatible with expo.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [docz](https://www.docz.site/), afaik they have react-native support.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will give it a try soon and make sure it works.
Storybook has also react-native support , but for some reason if your project is made using expo, they are not compatible.